# Since Which Exact Version(s) does git branch (git-branch) support the --format Option?

Tags: git, git-branch

I find the "`--format`" option quite handy.

> *in more detail especially the "`%(refname:short)`" directive within which is (at which Git ["`git`"] version is also unknown to me and could be considered bonus on the question) the fallback on the "`--pretty=format:...`" option notation, but anyway...  .*

Question is, since when does this "`git branch`" ("`git-branch`") support the

```
--format="%(refname:short)
```

option/value?

Additionally I would appreciate if the answer next to the concrete Git version would also offer a small test script (shell/bash) that would help me to formally verify the answer is correct. I just would appreciate that, it's not required by this website's terms IIRC, so just saying. Let me know if you would prefer a bounty for that and how high you would prefer it to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "formally verify the answer is correct"

Comment: @LightBender: Yeah, that is over the boundaries of subjective I must admit. Could be something exemplary: referencing official documentation that lists concrete version numbers (autoritative) and  a short script that parses such documentation as hypertext highlighting the information as precise and correct, or anything else creatively. Maybe just something additional in an executable form next to information passed by humans, but I don't know (IDK). I'm not too academic if that is what you're concerned about ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-branch` was extended to include the format options from `git-for-each-ref` in v2.13.0, the git online documentation first references it in [v2.13.2](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/2.13.2).

## How to find the answer

To hunt it down required a little light detective work, but the git source code is pretty well maintained, so that helps.

Because I knew the functionality is provided by `git-for-each-ref`, I figured the integration would be minor and might not be easily found by looking at the source code itself, so I went to to documentation for `git-branch` as it would have been updated with the new options when the functionality was added.

With a file to narrow things down, it was pretty easy to find the oldest commit with `--format` in the diff by using the `git-log`

```
git log -S--format -- Documentation/git-branch.txt
```

Armed with the commit hash (there was only one) I could then use `git-for-each-ref` to find the tags that contain the change, and by that identify the earliest version containing the commit.

```
git for-each-ref --contains 3d9e4ce3eb
```

That provided me with v2.13.0, then I checked the web site and found that the next available version of the documentation was v2.13.2.

Comment: You mean the/that website does say so for the first time when you select the git version "2.13.2"? - BTW interesting that a lot of useful stuff came in with 2.13.

Comment: If you could add that to your answer it would be much appreciated. Sounds all too legit, if not someone VonC jumps by and blasts it all off, just let me know about the bonus.

Comment: @hakre Added to the answer, I did amend down to v2.13.0, something was bothering me and looking into it further, the versions in the documentation aren't for stable releases (like I thought). Reading the release notes more carefully, the issues related git for-each-ref and branch were apparently efficiency issues, not major breaking issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your efforts, I really like the explanation given on how to find that out about git by using git on git's git repository :)